# Is it possible to transparently trigger callbacks when async functions suspend / resume?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback, middleware

I do realize that I could wrap individual awaits, but I'm looking for more of transparent / middleware solution that could wrap an async function and trigger pre / post callbacks on every await inside.

A pseudocode example of the desired functionality:

```
const suspendCallback () => console.log('Releasing the event loop');
const resumeCallback () => console.log('Reclaiming the event loop');

let work1 = () => new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => null, 1000))
let work2 = () => new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => null, 1000))
let work3 = () => new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => null, 1000))

// somehow bind the callbacks to this function:

const doTheThing = async () => {
  await work1();
  await work2();
  await work3();
};

doTheThing();

// Would print 'Releasing the event loop' each time doTheThing
// suspends, and 'Reclaiming the event loop' each time execution
// is resumed (the promise resolves). Thus:

> 'Releasing the event loop'
  'Reclaiming the event loop'
  'Releasing the event loop'
  'Reclaiming the event loop'
  'Releasing the event loop'
  'Reclaiming the event loop'
```

Comment: What do you need this for? What is your goal?

Comment: I'm playing around with ideas for a state store and pondering the ways one might handle an action that contains multiple asynchronous calls. The specific goal would be to toggle various flags in the store on suspending/resuming, but to do so without having to explicitly thunk each promise. Due to the involvement of shared proxies, there isn't an isolated context to rely on (and any context I fabricate would need to be cached/restored, resulting in the same requirement). Mostly I'm just having fun exploring the boundaries of JS.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) in node.js, which [can track promises](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_promise_execution_tracking).

There is no standard builtin construct in the language for this. If you want to build your own framework based on such a thing, go for generator functions instead and provide a runner that steps through the yielded tasks.